# OR condition in Grails Shiro tag

Tags: grails, tags, shiro

I am doing a two level menu and I want to show some entries if the user has certain permissions.

I dont want to show the first level of the menu if the user doesn't have permissions to any other submenu because it would display an empty list of results.

I'll put some code to explain it better. This could be an example of the menu:

```
<ul>
    <shiro:hasPermission permission="foo">
        <li> foo</li>
    </shiro:hasPermission>
    <shiro:hasPermission permission="bar">
        <li> bar</li>
    </shiro:hasPermission>
</ul>
```

Is it there a way to wrap the `<ul>` somehow to ask if the user has `foo` or `bar` permission?

I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and Shiro plugin 1.2.1

UPDATE WITH SOLUTION:

Finally I've created a new tagLib that extends the ShiroTagLib and has the desired function:

```
class ShiroTagLib extends org.apache.shiro.grails.ShiroTagLib {
    /**
     * This tag only writes its body to the output if the current user
     * have any of the given permissions provided in a separated comma String.
     */
    def hasAnyPermission = { attrs, body ->
        def permissions = attrs["permissions"]
        if (!permissions){
            throwTagError("Tag [hasAnyPermission] must have [permissions] attribute")
            }
        def permissionsList = permissions.split(',')
        for (permission in permissionsList) {
            if (checkPermission([permission: permission], "hasPermission")) {
                // Output the body text.
                        out << body()
                return out
                }
            }
        }
}
```

with this you can do `<shiro:hasAnyPermission permissions="foo,bar">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this but the `hasAnyRole` tag from the Shiro plugin is likely the easiest way.

```
<shiro:hasAnyRole in="foo,bar">

<ul>
    <shiro:hasPermission permission="foo">
        <li> foo</li>
    </shiro:hasPermission>
    <shiro:hasPermission permission="bar">
        <li> bar</li>
    </shiro:hasPermission>
</ul>

</shiro:hasAnyRole>
```

You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pledbrook/grails-shiro/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/org/apache/shiro/grails/ShiroTagLib.groovy) for the tag library for more information.

**Update**

Based on the comment provided there is another option which is based on permissions.

```
<g:set var="hasSomePermission" value="${false}" />
<shiro:hasPermission permission="foo">
  <g:set var="hasSomePermission" value="${true}" />
</shiro:hasPermission>
<shiro:hasPermission permission="bar">
  <g:set var="hasSomePermission" value="${true}" />
</shiro:hasPermission>
...
<g:if test="${hasSomePermission}">
...
</g:if>
```

The Shiro plugin doesn't provide a logical OR tag for permissions like it does with roles, so the above is another approach. Using this same idea you could DRY it up with your own tag library.

Comment: Thats the way I'm doing this right now, but I would like a method that looks closely into the user permissions instead the user role.  Something like hasAnyPermission (which dont exists)